# Accessing Authentication variable from LogoutHandler or LogoutFilter in Spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-security

In one of my project I have configured Spring Security to handle user authentication.

My config file looks like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login default-target-url="/main" login-page="/" always-use-default-target="true" username-parameter="userId" password-parameter="password" />
    <custom-filter ref="customLogoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER"/-->
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />

<beans:bean id="customLogoutHandler" class="com.somepack.CustomLogoutHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="customLogoutHandler"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="customLogoutFilter"/>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customLogoutFilter" class="com.somepack.CustomLogoutFilter">
    <beans:property name="reportDir" value="/tmp/reports"/> 
</beans:bean>
```

My CustomLogoutFilter class looks like

```
public class CustomLogoutFilter implements LogoutHandler {
    private String reportDir;
    public String getReportDir() {
        return reportDir;
    }
    public void setReportDir(String reportDir) {
        this.reportDir = reportDir;
    }
    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        File folder = new File(reportDir, userName);
        deleteDir(folder); //delete function to delete Logged User specific directory
        logService.info("Logout", userName, EventCode.LOGOUT,
                String.format("User %s logged out successfully", userName));
        for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            printcookies(cookie);
            if (cookie.equals("JSESSIONID")) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        request.getSession().invalidate();
    }   
}
```

But this piece of code is not working as the filter is getting called at the very first request for the Login page (even it may would get called in every request) and I am getting an NullPointerException in the 
String userName = authentication.getName() line.

In fact instead of Using LogoutFilter if I use Logouthandler, I get the same error:

My handler looks like this:

```
public class CustomLogoutHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{
    private String reportDir;
    public String getReportDir() {
        return reportDir;
    }
    public void setReportDir(String reportDir) {
        this.reportDir = reportDir;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        File folder = new File(reportDir, userName);
        deleteDir(folder);
        logService.info("Logout", userName, EventCode.LOGOUT, String.format("User %s logged out successfully", userName));
        super.handle(request, response, authentication);
    }
```

and config file changed to:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login default-target-url="/main" login-page="/" always-use-default-target="true" username-parameter="userId" password-parameter="password" />
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="customLogoutHandler" logout-url="/logout" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customLogoutHandler" class="sequent.ui.security.CustomLogoutHandler">
    <beans:property name="reportDir" value="/tmp/reports" />
</beans:bean>
```

Not sure how can I resolve this issue.

Please help.

In short my basic requirement is that, I need to access the User Principal in the Logout mechanism which triggered when either User clicks on the Logout button or the session expires. I need the User information because the application creates temporary folder in the name of logged user which I need to delete at the time when he log off.

Appreciate your help please!!

-Raul

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `filerProcessesUrl` of the `LogoutFilter` to "/" which means that every time a user browses to the domain root, the filter will attempt to logout the user. Use a specific logout URL (or the default value) and check whether the user is actually authenticated before you try to do a logout (make sure the `Authentication` instance isn't null).

If you need to deal with session timeouts, where the user fails to logout, then you will also have to implement an `HttpSessionListener` which identifies the user from the session and performs whatever clean-up you need. This would be added to your `web.xml` file. Note that this class isn't invoked during a user request, so you can't use the `SecurityContext` to obtain information about the user, you must get it from the session object which is passed to the listener before the session is invalidated.